# how to insert charecter into object name?

Tags: vba, visual-studio

is there a way to insert a character such as 0, 1 and 2 into a text box name, as i have a text box named TB_Result0, TB_Result1 and TB_Result2?

```
num(counter) = "TB_Result" & counter & ".text"
```

I can do it instead by doing:

```
    num(0) = TB_Result0.Text
    num(1) = TB_Result1.Text
    num(2) = TB_Result2.Text
```

Thanks

Comment: What language are you actually working in?  VBA is usually VB6 or code in an Office Application.  Visual Studio usually refers to VB.Net, though it could be a super old version for VB6...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work

```
    For i = 0 To 2
        num (i) = Me.Controls("TB_Result" & i)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming VB.Net, you can search for the control, which will find it no matter how far nested it is inside containers other than the form itself:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 2
    Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find("TB_Result" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(ctl) Then
        num(i) = ctl.Text
    End If
Next
```

The [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) function will search recursively into nested containers looking for matches. It returns an **array** of matches as it is possible to have more than one control with the same name (usually due to dynamic controls created at run time).  The [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__) part gives you either the first element in the returned array, or the default value, which in this case will be Nothing. Lastly, if "ctl" isn't Nothing then we have a match and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks that works even though I have no idea what its doing.